# How to politely insist on being called Mr [Lastname] in a professional setting?

Tags: professionalism, communication

It is very important to me that I am addressed by my family name in a professional setting, e.g. Mr Doe. Often, new employees will default to a casual tone and automatically call me by my first name, e.g. John. I would like to nip this behaviour in the bud as soon as possible, but I also do not want to strain our relationship by sounding pompous or arrogant. Were it the other way around, it would be simple; if they called me Mr Doe I could say "Please, call me John". "Please, call me Mr Doe" sounds rude to my ears.

If my region is important, I am Canadian, but answers from the USA or UK would be interesting as well.

I see three possible approaches to this problem:

Direct route: Simply tell them. "Please, call me Mr Doe" sounds rude, but perhaps there is a better wording, or perhaps it is not generally considered as rude as I believe it to be.

Subtle route: Ask someone else to correct the employee after the meeting. Perhaps I could ask them to mention something like "By the way, he prefers being called Mr Doe".

Even subtler route: Include the new employee in conversations with people who know to refer to me as Mr Doe, and they'll get the hint.

Comment: Note: downvotes and poor reception were the result of the post being asked to set up a fictional scenario in a story the OP is writing. Given how at-odds this kind of behaviour is at most modern workplaces it does make sense to close it since we don't tend to encourage hypotheticals.

Comment: Why don't we encourage hypotheticals? It's a realistic scenario that may resonate with a future reader.

Comment: Will you also be learning everyones last name and marital status and addressing them as Mister, Mrs, Ms, Master etc,.?

Comment: Why is it important?  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have been introduced to large company's COB, Presiddent, SVP, etc, by their first name.  Why do you have expectations to be called Mr.  {last name}.  Is this a cultural bias on your part?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Canada and America have far too informal cultures to not come across as arrogant.

Except for the military, and a few outside exceptions, it is simply seen as being full of oneself.

Even "Doctor" has fallen out of favor, unless you are an MD or DDS, or other medical doctor.

Sorry, there is no way to do this without inviting ridicule to oneself

Comment: The only instances of people who insist on being called by their family name is because they HATE their first name. But then they're very upfront about this - "hey, I really hate John, can you please call me Doe?" (no Mr. / Ms., though, this does sound pompous)